# Использование ограничения шаблона SFINAE при полной специализации

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

Необходимо получать некий идентификатор для типа, сделано через полную специализацию шаблона.

```
template<typename T> struct ids;
template<> struct ids<int> { static const int id = 1; };
template<> struct ids<float> { static const int id = 2; };
```

Возможно ли аналогично специализировать шаблон для любого типа, проходящего ограничение `std::is_class`?
Не совсем представляю, как это правильно сделать. Думал, что это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<A>::value>>
struct ids { static const int id = 3 };
```

Comment: можно, но это будет частичная специализация

Comment: @user7860670, c `bool` - аргументом шаблона по-умолчанию?

Comment: почему с bool? у вас же почти правильно написано - добавлять второй typename и по нему делать частичную специализацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename x_Value, typename x_Enabled = void>
struct ids;

template<>
struct ids<int, void>
{ static inline constexpr int const id{1}; };

template<>
struct ids<float, void>
{ static inline constexpr int const id{2}; };

template<typename x_Value>
struct ids<x_Value, ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_class_v<x_Value>>>
{ static inline constexpr int const id{3}; };

static_assert(1 == ids<int>::id);
static_assert(2 == ids<float>::id);

struct something{};

static_assert(3 == ids<something>::id);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6ax86d

Comment: Только у ТСа 11 стандарт (судя по метке), так что надо с `::value`, `::type` и `inline` разобраться

Comment: @dIm0n, да и явно дописать `typename`

Comment: А зачем в полных специализациях писать `void`, когда он по-умолчанию?

Comment: @dIm0n Да с с++11 придется писать `typename ::std::enable_if< ::std::is_class<x_Value>::value >::type`

Comment: @mkkik Можно не писать, но при специализации это бывает полезно.